# SQL - hours format in between

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have here my sql case statement.

```
CASE WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') 
            and DATEPART(HOUR,dt.start_time) BETWEEN 7 AND 17 THEN '103856' --WEEKDAY
     WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') 
            and DATEPART(HOUR,dt.start_time) BETWEEN 17 AND 22 THEN '103857' --WEEKDAY-EVENING
    WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 'WEEKEND'  
END
```

How am i going to format `BETWEEN 7 AND 17` like this `BETWEEN 7 AND 16:59:59` ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide:  (1) Sample data; (2) desired results; (3) an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I'm sorry Sir. Now i figure it out. I used the wrong format. i should have used **DATEPART(HH,dt.start_time) BETWEEN 7 AND 16** so it will also capture 16:59:59

Comment: @Grinex: Here's another one of Aaron's articles for you: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - thanks for this, gonna apply it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `DATEPART(HOUR,dt.start_time)`, Use `CAST(dt.start_time as time)` instead:

```
CASE WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') 
            and CAST(dt.start_time as time) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '16:59:59' THEN '103856' --WEEKDAY
     WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') 
            and CAST(dt.start_time as time) BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '21:59:59' THEN '103857' --WEEKDAY-EVENING
    WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 'WEEKEND'  
END
```

Also, I wouldn't use `BETWEEN...AND`, I would use `<=` and `>=`:

```
CASE WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') 
            and CAST(dt.start_time as time) >= '07:00:00' AND CAST(dt.start_time as time) <= '16:59:59' THEN '103856' --WEEKDAY
     WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') 
            and CAST(dt.start_time as time) >= '17:00:00' AND CAST(dt.start_time as time) <= '21:59:59' THEN '103857' --WEEKDAY-EVENING
    WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 'WEEKEND'  
END
```

Aaron Bertrand explains it way better then I could in his article called ["What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?"](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: alright! many thanks, it also works. I will try to apply Aaron Bertrand habits to kick in the future

Answer (score 2):

This is an effective method. It is not converting to varchar to determine the weekday and works regardless of the local setting for language.

This would mess with your current code:

```
SET LANGUAGE Italian;  
SELECT DATENAME(weekday,'12/5/2007')
```

This ignores the language setting:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN datediff(d, 0, dt.start_time)%7 < 5
     THEN 
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,dt.start_time) BETWEEN 7 AND 16 
            THEN '103856' --WEEKDAY
     ELSE 
       -- not sure what you are trying to do here
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,dt.start_time) BETWEEN 17 AND 22
            THEN '103857' --WEEKDAY-EVENING
       END
     END
ELSE 
  'WEEKEND'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change 17 to 16, because the hour of 16:59:59 is 16, while starting with 17:00:00 it is 17.

```
CASE WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') 
            and DATEPART(HOUR,dt.start_time) BETWEEN 7 AND 16 THEN '103856' --WEEKDAY
     WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') 
            and DATEPART(HOUR,dt.start_time) BETWEEN 17 AND 22 THEN '103857' --WEEKDAY-EVENING
    WHEN DATENAME(WeekDay, dt.start_time) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 'WEEKEND'  
END
```

And if you want to filter for the time range form 17:00:00 to 21:59:59 you need to change the second between expression as well.